# .mov format videos are not playing in MPMovieplayer in ios 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayer

I am selecting a videos from library .videos are not playing in iphone 4s(ios5) and it is playing in iphone 4(ios4).Videos are in .mov format.I am taking mp4 video statically and it is playing.Is there any reason? Please give any advice. Thanks in advance

movieplayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videourl];

```
    NSLog(@"url--%@",videourl);
if([movieplayer respondsToSelector:@selector(view)])
 {
    movieplayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    [movieplayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:movieplayer.view];
     movieplayer.shouldAutoplay=true;
    [movieplayer play];
 }
```

It shows black screen

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your video codec.

according to Apple web site only these codecs are supported.

> **H.264 video**: up to 1.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Low-Complexity version of the H.264 Baseline Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats
>   **MPEG-4 video**: up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats